# Discord js Messages Leaderboard

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, leaderboard

Hewo all. I'm actually trying to create a living leaderboard (by this, i mean the leaderboard is send to a specific channel and it updates every 30 secondes for example) for messages. (Top 10 users)

Can you give me an example code? I can't find a thing about living leaderboard so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the Discord.js Guide, they have a good tutorial for making a currency system that you should be able to modify for your needs. [Here it is](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.htm)

Also a warning, sending messages to a channel repeatedly may be interpreted as spam, so watch out for that as your bot may be disabled.